# OO Design: Multiple instances but Static Callbacks

Tags: c++, c, oop, callback

I'm trying to wrap a C library in a C++. The library defines some callback functions such as  `void (*callback)(void*)`, which in my OO class must be static, obviously.

My problem is finding the correct instance of the class from within the callback function. The callback parameter is not known at the time of creating the object.

```
class CObj
{
public:
  CObj()
  {
    c_lib_start(CObj::CallbackFunc);
  }
  static void CallbackFunc(void* arg)
  {
    c_lib_type* data = (c_lib_type*)arg;
    // ... handle data callback
  }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  CObj obj1;
  CObj obj2; // will call the same callback function as obj1! can this be avoided?
}
```

EDIT:

After some thinking, draft of my best attempt for solution:

```
class CObj
{
public:
  CObj(void (*pFuncPtr)(void*))
  {
    c_lib_start(pFuncPtr);
  }
  void CallbackFunc(void* arg)
  {
    c_lib_type* data = (c_lib_type*)arg;
    // ... handle data callback
  }
}

// globals. templated?
CObj* g_obj1 = NULL;
void FuncPtr1(void* arg) { g_obj1->CallbackFunc(arg); }

CObj* g_obj2 = NULL;
void FuncPtr2(void* arg) { g_obj2->CallbackFunc(arg); }

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  g_obj1 = new CObj(FuncPtr1);
  g_obj2 = new CObj(FuncPtr2);
}
```

Comment: If `c_lib_type` has a field for client-supplied data, you can use that. Otherwise, I'm afraid you're out of luck.

Comment: What is `c_lib_type` ?

Comment: Can the callback occur at any time out of the blue, or does it only occur in response to your application performing some action involving a known CObj instance? If it's the latter, you can resort to the ugly solution of putting a `static CObj* currentThis` in CObj and setting it to the correct value before triggering the callback.

Comment: @DieterLücking c_lib_type is an abstract data type, originated from the C library.

Comment: @dlf the callback might occur at any time.

Comment: @Angew unfortunately no.

Comment: Is this a secret C library or is it available to the public?

Comment: How does your class relate to the callback function? For this to make any sense, your class must somehow be linked to the parameter of the callback. Is it your class that creates this callback parameter (for example as done when calling CreateThread and such functions)? In that case, I have a solution. Otherwise, you are indeed out of luck because in that case your specification doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Something like the solution in your edit should work as long as the number of CObjs is small and known at compile time. But I think you want to reference g_obj1/2 in main() instead of creating new automatic  CObj*s.

Comment: @Lundin The C library is a webserver, which invokes a callback on every new connection and on every data TX/RX. I want to maintain several servers open simultaneously and to keep a list of open connections on each of them. The callback argument is the connection/request data, but while valuable, has nothing to do with my OO doings.

Comment: If you were the one creating the parameter to the callback, you could have wrapped the parameter into a classic "hack" struct where you append the `this` pointer of your class instance in the end. It's an elegant solution which actually has well-defined behavior. But it would seem you can't use it in this case.

Comment: The solution with a file scope function for each instance of the class is ugly though. Better then to create a base class, which contains the bulk of the code. Then inherit it and make every child a singleton with its own unique callback function.

Answer (score 1):

A useful C-callback function has a signature like `R function(void* user_data)` or with additional arguments `R function(A0 a0, A1 a1, ... AN an, void* user_data)`. The C library should provide a function like register_function(function_type, void* user_data).

Having that, you can register the pair of a C++ object and a static member function by calling register_function(&Class::static_member_function, this).
At invocation you cast the user data to the class object passed to the registration.

Without above, you have a dilemma. You will store the calling object in a global variable and use that in the callback function, making the callback bounded to a single object, only!.

Answer (score 0):

Your edit suggests the following idea:

```
template<size_t SerialNumber>
class CObjFactory
{
private:
   static std::weak_ptr<CObj> weakObj;

   static void CallbackFuncWrapper(void* arg)
   {
      auto strongObj = weakObj.lock();
      if(strongObj == nullptr)
         return;
      strongObj->CallbackFunc(arg);
   }

public:
  static std::shared_ptr<CObj> Create()
  {
     auto strongObj = std::make_shared<CObj>(CallbackFuncWrapper);
     weakObj = strongObj;
     return strongObj;
  }    
};

template<size_t SerialNumber>
std::weak_ptr<CObj> CObjFactory<SerialNumber>::weakObj;

void main()
{
  std::shared_ptr<CObj> o1 = CObjFactory<0>::Create();
  std::shared_ptr<CObj> o2 = CObjFactory<1>::Create();
}
```

This is certainly a hack, but I think you're stuck with hacks given the constraints you're under.